# Finding the unit quaternion for the regular octahedron

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am given this figure of a regular octahedron and I have to find the unit quaternion.

In the symmetry group of the regular octahedron what is the unit quaternion that represents a 90 degree rotation about the semi x-axis $\lambda i, \lambda >0$ . The rotation appears to be counter clockwise to an observer at point A.

[image]

At point A, I am just given the i vector and I know that I have a 90 degree rotation. So, $\theta = 90^{\circ}$. There is also $ \alpha = cos \theta$, but if I just plug in 90 degrees right now, I will just have 0.

If I have a 90 degree rotation. Then

$2\theta = 90^{\circ}$

$\theta = 45^{\circ}$

$ \alpha = 45^{\circ} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

The norm of u is 1 and $u^2$ is 1 so I have
$ u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+ \lambda i$
so $u^2 = \frac{1}{2} + (\lambda)^2(i)^2$ (that $i^2$ is not imaginary..it's a vector)

and then I have to solve for lambda

$1 = \frac{1}{2} + (\lambda)^2(i)^2$
using the ...alright I'm forgetting my terminology here but I know $\sqrt(1^2+0^2+0^2) = \sqrt(1) = 1$ because i is my only vector and I have (1,0,0)

$1 = \frac{1}{2} + (\lambda)^2$

$1-\frac{1}{2} =  (\lambda)^2$

$\frac{1}{2} =  (\lambda)^2$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \lambda$

$ u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i$

Is that the unit quaternion? I'm kind of lost.